# Find if there is a pair (a,b) in given array such that a = b*2

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

Given an array, how can I find if there are two numbers (a, b) in it such that a = b*2

In the most efficient way. I solved it on O(n*nlog(n)) with hashtable and AVL,

but they say it can be done in O(nlog(n)) at worst case and O(n) at average case.

For example:

arr = [1,3,12,2,6,7]

Output:  True

Explanation: 12 = 6*2

Comment: Do you want the actual values (a and b) or just a boolean result?

Comment: boolean results

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Java/C/C++/python, anything u want, but better to be algorithm ...I can write it as code there is no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linear time, linear space solution:

- Loop over all elements in the array.
- Maintain a set while doing so.
- If current value's half is present in the map or if current value's double is present in the map, return true, else return false.

**Pseudocode:**

```
set = []
for element in array: 
    if set.contains(element * 2) or (element % 2 == 0 and set.contains(element / 2)):
       return true
    set.add(element)
return false
```

Comment: this is specific solution in Python right? like in java I can't do something like set.contains in O(1) ..

Comment: @TariqGanem This is actually a pseudocode, not something you can execute with a compiler or interpreter, just the idea. In java, you do have HashSet, where you can do set.contains() in O(1) on average case.

Comment: @TariqGanem If you want to avoid HashSet, then sort the array and do binary search for each element. So, it is O(n log(n)) + O(n log(n)) = 2 * O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n)) asymptotically.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Can you elaborate?

Comment: It will work since you added the element after checking. Nm

Comment: @nice_dev just a small change `element / 2` needs to be only checked after the element is an even number. For example, 3/2 = 1 . if 1 is present you will return `true` which is not correct

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Fixed that minor one.

Comment: As long as `/` is not an integer divide you don't need to check if `element` is a multiple of 2 since `3/2=1.5`

Comment: @Nick Makes sense. In python it's 1.5 and in java it's 1. Just made it portable across languages.

Comment: Alternative, loop twice, looking for whether 2n is in the set each time.

Comment: @btilly Yes, doable but you will have to be careful with 0's count.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Java.

```
public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
        int zc =0;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(set.contains(arr[i]*2) || (arr[i]%2==0 && set.contains(arr[i]/2))){
                return true;
            }
            set.add(arr[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Time complexity is O(n) considering Hashing operation is O(1)